# Trouble obtaining elements of string split from list

Tags: python

I am reading a document as follows:

```
Title of document
[[subtitle of document]] 
etc
```

I am opening it with doc = open(path, 'r').read(), and I want to be able to just select the first and second lines.

When I use doc.split("\n") it returns a list ['Title of document', 'subtitle of document', 'etc'] as expected. Also as expected doc.split("\n")[0] returns 'Title of document', but for some reason doc.split("\n")[1] returns "list index out of range". How could this be, when it shows element 1 as being there in the list?

Comment: Please post a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the "list index out of range" because you are splitting a string.
do a `print(type(doc))` and you'll see.

The result of `doc.split('\n')` will be the list you want. After that, you can extract the values by indexing them.

```
doc = open('example.txt', 'r').read()
print(type(doc))

doc_list = doc.split('\n')
print(type(doc_list))
print(f'first: {doc_list[0]}')
print(f'second: {doc_list[1]}')
```

Then the result

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'list'>
first: Title of document
second: [[subtitle of document]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly open(path, 'r').readlines(), that gives you a list containing every lines of the file. You can print it to see if you got every lines you want and access them with array access as you did with the split. `with` is also a python keyword you want to search on the documentation.

Comment: I tried that and print(doc) shows me the correct list, but doc[0] gives "index out of range" as do other indices

Comment: This will be the same as `doc.split("\n")`, so how does it solve the problem?